# Dynamic created nested model in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

In my use case I need to create nested models dynamically, reusing model elements. E.g. I'd like to define an adress model, and resue it for a person model:

```py
from pydantic import Field, create_model

name = Field('a name')
street = Field('a street')
city = Field('a city')
address = create_model('address', street=street, city=city)
person = create_model('person', name=name, address=address)

locationdata = dict(street='somestreet', city='sometown')
print(address.parse_obj(locationdata).dict())

alicedata = dict(name='alice', address=locationdata)
print(person.parse_obj(alicedata).dict())

# Gives:
#
# {'street': 'somestreet', 'city': 'sometown'}
# {'name': 'alice'}
```

The locationdata never 'reaches' the person, although used directly it works. Any suggestions? Is `create_model` the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `person` as:

```
person = create_model('person', name=name, address=(address, ...))  # address model, required
# OR
person = create_model('person', name=name, address=address())  # instantiate default value
```

Because [`create_model`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) defines fields by either a tuple of the form `(<type>, <default value>)` or just a default value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spelling it out to me, works perfectly fine! :-)